# Referencing different coloumn as ranges between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame/ list that gives and ID and a number

```
1.  25
2.  36
3.  10
4.  18
5.  12
```

This first list is effectively a list of objects with the number of objects contained in each eg. bricks in a wall, so a a list or walls with the number of bricks in each.
I have a second that contains a a full list of the objects being referred to in that above list and a second attribute for each.

```
1.   3
2.   4
3.   2
4.   8
5.   5
```

etc.
 in the weak example I'm stringing together this would be a list of the weight of each brick in all walls.

so my first list give me the ranges i would like to average in the second list, or I would like as an end result a list of walls with the average weight of each brick per wall.

ie average the attributes of 1-25, 26-62 ... 89-101

my idea so far was to create a data frame with two coloumns

```
1. 1 25
2. 26 62
3. n
4. n
5. 89 101
```

and then attempt to create a third column that uses the first two as x and y in a `mean(table2$coloumn1[x:y])` type formula, but I can't get anything to work.

the end result could probably looks something like this

```
1.   3.2
2.   6.5
3.   3
4.   7.9
5.   8.5
```

is there a way to do it like this or does anyone have a more elegant solution.

Comment: This looks like a well thought out question, but it could use better formatting, clearer expected output and a more easily reproduced example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this... set the low and high limits of your ranges and then use `mapply` to work out the mean over the appropriate rows of `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),no=c(25,36,10,18,12))
df2 <- data.frame(obj=1:100,att=sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE))

df1$low <- cumsum(c(1,df1$no[-nrow(df1)]))
df1$high <- pmin(cumsum(df1$no),nrow(df2))
df1$meanatt <- mapply(function(l,h) mean(df2$att[l:h]), df1$low, df1$high)

df1
  id no low high  meanatt
1  1 25   1   25 4.760000
2  2 36  26   61 5.527778
3  3 10  62   71 5.800000
4  4 18  72   89 5.111111
5  5 12  90  100 4.454545
```